# ORA-28759: failure to open file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a problem.
When I use `UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET` Oracle says me next errors:

```
ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
ORA-28759: failure to open file
```

Previously, I use Oracle Wallet Manager for setup the Sertificate from website "https://focus-api.kontur.ru/api3/". Cannot understand, what am I doing wrong.

```
DECLARE
    HTTP_REQ      UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    HTTP_RESP     UTL_HTTP.RESP;
    URL_TEXT      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('file:d:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\wallet', 'password');
    HTTP_REQ  := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('https://focus-api.kontur.ru/api3/req?inn=7714037390');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(HTTP_REQ, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
    HTTP_RESP := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(HTTP_REQ);
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            URL_TEXT := null;
            UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(HTTP_RESP, URL_TEXT, TRUE);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(URL_TEXT);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN EXIT;
        END;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(HTTP_RESP);
END;
/
```